# How to get width of element in javascript

Tags: javascript, height, width, getelementbyid

I am trying to get the width and height of an element. My element is a DIV with the id of "page".

The current code is not working as my div has a border and it allows my button to go out of the border.

I have tried the .offsetWidth as well as .clientwidth - Both returned null values.

```
var buttonState = document.getElementById("clickMe");
var maxArea = document.getElementById("page");
var pageWidth = maxArea.width;
var pageHeight = maxArea.height;
var screenWidth = 0;
var screenHeight = 0;
var buttonSize = 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.getComputedStyle("page").getPropertyValue('font-size');
```

Answer (score 0):

> document.getElementById("page").style.width

Comment: I am getting an error in console that says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"

Comment: That means the element isn't present when your JavaScript is run.

Comment: Double-check that your div has id="page" rather than class="page". Also it is a good idea to post the relevant part of the HTML as well.